# Periodically storing the results of snmpwalk to a file in Linux

Tags: snmp, snmpwalk

I'm running `snmpwalk` on Linux and saving the output to a file using

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c  public 192.168.129.122:17225  1.3.6.1.4.1.2.1.1.1 >> SNMPWALK_SS
```

If the value of one parameter is saved to a file with

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2.1.1.1.82.0 = Gauge32: 0
```

then the name of this value is `82=82,SNMP_PAL_ACTIVE_SESSION,0,1`

I want to save the `snmpwalk` value for  a service at each of a list of times that would be read from a file. My final outcome would be like this:

```
Mon Feb 25 11:35:02 IST 2013
SNMP_PAL_ACTIVE_SESSION : 10
```

Is there any tool to achieve this task?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt there is a tool already which does this, but you could write it yourself in python or perl pretty easily. I didn't quite understand your question, did you want to count the number of occurances of SNMP_PAL_ACTIVE_SESSION? Or do you need to do something more complicated like add up the values? Expand your example and explain the logic in English.

This is some bash to get you started

```
#!/bin/bash
snmpwalk -v 2c -c  public 192.168.129.122:17225  1.3.6.1.4.1.2.1.1 > /tmp/snmpwalk.out
COUNT=`grep -c SNMP_PAL_ACTIVE_SESSION /tmp/snmpwalk.out`
date >> ~/snmp.sessions.log
echo "SNMP_PAL_ACTIVE_SESSION : $COUNT" >> ~/snmp.sessions.log
```